# What is 'dnd' or 'DnD'?

Tags: gvim, version

`:version` shows `-dnd`. `:help dnd` reads:

> ```
> *+dnd*        Support for DnD into the "~ register |quote_~|.
> ```

What does 'dnd' or 'DnD' stand for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It stands for "drag'n'drop".

See `:help quote_~`:

> The read-only `"~` register stores the dropped text from the last drag'n'drop
> operation.  When something has been dropped onto Vim, the `"~` register is
> filled in and the `<Drop>` pseudo key is sent for notification.  You can remap
> this key if you want; the default action (for all modes) is to insert the
> contents of the `"~` register at the cursor position.
> *{only available when compiled with the `+dnd` feature, currently only with the
> GTK GUI}*
>
> Note: The `"~` register is only used when dropping plain text onto Vim.
> Drag'n'drop of URI lists is handled internally.

Comment: some of the abbreviations vim comes up with are really baffling